# LINQ not evaluating check for null object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm wondering why my linq statement doesn't properly evaluate the null check on the Agency object which is a property of the Users model.

```
var invalidUsers = this.DbContext.Users.Where(p => p.Agency != null).ToList();    
var invalidUsersList = invalidUsers.Where(p => p.Agency != null).ToList();
```

When I run the code above, the first line returns a list of all Users, regardless of the Agency object being null or not. However, the second line executes and properly filters the list and returns a list that is correctly returning Users where Agency is not null.

Comment: In first case you are likely interacting with the database itself therefore it is set in SQL to not be null or whatever. And in second case you are running on a simple collection which would actually check for it being null, not build an SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are since this appears to be a foreign key table you need to include it first in LINQ so it can query against it.

So something like.

```
var invalidUsers = await this.DbContext.Users
.Include(p => p.Agency)
.Where(p => p.Agency != null)
.ToListAsync();
```

Give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: OP is not using asynchronous code, so I suggest to add a synchronous version as well.

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple! Thank you!

Comment: The original code is actually asynchronous, I only modified it here as I was testing and didn't need/want the methods to be async.

Comment: I figured it was, which is why I posted the async version.